# REQUEST_URI not printing a var when using switch case

Tags: php

I am trying to check the `URl` and load a different variable for each domain and their paths like `example.com and example.com/dir` but when i run `echo $region` i get nothing. Even tried to `echo $domain` but i get nothing too.

```
global $region;

 $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // Get current url
 $domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST); // Get only path
 preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs);
 $domain = !empty($regs['domain']) ? $regs['domain'] : '';

 echo $domain;  <--- not printing

 switch ($domain) {
  case 'example.com':
    $region = 'usa'; <--- not printing
  break;

  case 'two_example.com':
    $region = 'pie'; <--- not printing
  break;

default:
  echo $domain;  <--- not printing
  break;
}
```

Comment: The $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] will give you only the part after domain, i.e. /URI/
So $domain turns out to be null because parse_url takes full URLs. So you might need to check the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] as well.

Comment: @Karan tried to check this but still nothing  $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; // Get current url

Comment: @rob.m Just run `var_dump($_SERVER);` to inspect all values.

Comment: @Karan changed to PHP_URL_HOST and resolved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change

```
 $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

to

```
url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Comment: As already pointed out, `REQUEST_URI` does not include the protocol or host parts, so it doesn't matter how you parse it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thanks, you are right, I had forgotten to include that change too. Answer updated now